# Remove port from the url

Tags: configuration, port, lighttpd

How can I change the url `http://localhost:8080` to `http://localhost` in a lighttpd server..

I searched on Google, but no luck..

My current .conf file

```
server.document-root = "/mnt/sdcard/www"
dir-listing.activate = "enable"
server.errorlog = "/mnt/sdcard/wwwconf/server.log"

server.tag = "lighttpd/1.4.29 for Android"

server.port = 8080

index-file.names = ("index.php", "index.html", "index.htm", "home.php","home.html","home.htm")

fastcgi.server = (
  ".php" =>
        (( "host" => "127.0.0.1",
           "port" => 9003,
        ))
)
alias.url = ("/phpmyadmin" => "/data/data/com.andi.serverweb/files/phpmyadmin")

server.max-request-size = 1000000
server.network-backend = "writev"
server.upload-dirs =( "/data/data/com.andi.serverweb/files/lighttpd/tmp" )

mimetype.use-xattr  = "disable"

mimetype.assign             = (
  ".appcache"     =>    "text/cache-manifest",  
  ".pdf"          =>    "application/pdf",
  ".sig"          =>    "application/pgp-signature",
  ".spl"          =>    "application/futuresplash",
  ".class"        =>    "application/octet-stream",
  ".ps"           =>    "application/postscript",
  ".torrent"      =>    "application/x-bittorrent",
  ".dvi"          =>    "application/x-dvi",
  ".gz"           =>    "application/x-gzip",
  ".pac"          =>    "application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig",
  ".swf"          =>    "application/x-shockwave-flash",
  ".tar.gz"       =>    "application/x-tgz",
  ".tgz"          =>    "application/x-tgz",
  ".tar"          =>    "application/x-tar",
  ".zip"          =>    "application/zip",
  ".mp3"          =>    "audio/mpeg",
  ".m3u"          =>    "audio/x-mpegurl",
  ".wma"          =>    "audio/x-ms-wma",
  ".wax"          =>    "audio/x-ms-wax",
  ".ogg"          =>    "application/ogg",
  ".wav"          =>    "audio/x-wav",
  ".gif"          =>    "image/gif",
  ".jpg"          =>    "image/jpeg",
  ".jpeg"         =>    "image/jpeg",
  ".png"          =>    "image/png",
  ".xbm"          =>    "image/x-xbitmap",
  ".xpm"          =>    "image/x-xpixmap",
  ".xwd"          =>    "image/x-xwindowdump",
  ".css"          =>    "text/css",
  ".html"         =>    "text/html",
  ".htm"          =>    "text/html",
  ".js"           =>    "text/javascript",
  ".asc"          =>    "text/plain",
  ".c"            =>    "text/plain",
  ".cpp"          =>    "text/plain",
  ".log"          =>    "text/plain",
  ".conf"         =>    "text/plain",
  ".text"         =>    "text/plain",
  ".txt"          =>    "text/plain",
  ".spec"         =>    "text/plain",
  ".dtd"          =>    "text/xml",
  ".xml"          =>    "text/xml",
  ".mpeg"         =>    "video/mpeg",
  ".mpg"          =>    "video/mpeg",
  ".mov"          =>    "video/quicktime",
  ".qt"           =>    "video/quicktime",
  ".avi"          =>    "video/x-msvideo",
  ".asf"          =>    "video/x-ms-asf",
  ".asx"          =>    "video/x-ms-asf",
  ".wmv"          =>    "video/x-ms-wmv",
  ".bz2"          =>    "application/x-bzip",
  ".tbz"          =>    "application/x-bzip-compressed-tar",
  ".tar.bz2"      =>    "application/x-bzip-compressed-tar",
  ".odt"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
  ".ods"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
  ".odp"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
  ".odg"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics",
  ".odc"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart",
  ".odf"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula",
  ".odi"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image",
  ".odm"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master",
  ".ott"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template",
  ".ots"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template",
  ".otp"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template",
  ".otg"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template",
  ".otc"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart-template",
  ".otf"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template",
  ".oti"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image-template",
  ".oth"          =>    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web",
  ""              =>    "application/octet-stream",
)


server.modules   = ( 
    "mod_rewrite",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_access",
    "mod_auth",
    "mod_status",
    "mod_simple_vhost",
    "mod_evhost",
    "mod_userdir",
    "mod_secdownload",
    "mod_fastcgi",
    "mod_proxy",
    "mod_cgi",
    "mod_ssi",
    "mod_compress",
    "mod_usertrack",
    "mod_expire",
    "mod_rrdtool",
    "mod_accesslog" 
)
```

Comment: I know we have a running joke about running services on one's phone, but **it's a joke**.

Comment: @MichaelHampton no it's not a joke, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweb&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dbit+web+server+android it works out ok..

Comment: And besides, to run it on port 80 you would have to root the phone, and probably do other things as well, that are far outside our scope.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you put it on hold just because I'm running a server on my phone?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yeah I'm aware of the root issue, I just didn't what o do for removing the port from the url..

Comment: Yes, because running a web server on your phone is [not professional](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/4111/126632).

Comment: I have no idea what it is that entices people into thinking this is a good plan for anything other than novelty purposes, let far alone it being suitable for professional use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attempt to connect to `http://localhost`, your browser will use the default HTTP port, which is 80.

So to remove 8080 from the URL, your web server will need to be running on port 80. A quick glance at your config file suggests that you'll probably just need to change the `server.port` line.

```
server.port = 80
```

Of course if you're using 8080 because something is already running on this machine using port 80, or you're unable to use port 80 for some other reason (such as your program can't run as root so doesn't have permission to open ports below 1024) then you don't really have many options.

Comment: Yeah, it needs root for changing port below 1024, so no workaround?

Comment: No. Maybe you have a good reason, but running anything like this on a phone/tablet is just a waste of time and effort

Comment: Yes, but sometimes I don't have an alternative, anyway thanks for the answer, I'll root my Droid, if it works, I'll accept the answer..